# Setting TextStyle in flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-text, flutter-theme

How do I set the text style to `headline1` or `body1` like it is described in the "Material Text Scale: Modernizing Flutter Text Theming" section of the [Flutter 1.17 Announcement article](https://medium.com/flutter/announcing-flutter-1-17-4182d8af7f8e)

```
final TextStyle TEXT_STYLE = GoogleFonts.lato(textStyle: *something in here?*);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by creating a TextTheme object and using the available styles.

In your example:

```
final TextStyle TEXT_STYLE = GoogleFonts.lato(textStyle: TextTheme().bodyText1);
```

Answer (score 0):

The typographic style `headline1` was [deprecated after `v3.1.0-0.0.pre`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/TextTheme-class.html) in favour of `displayLarge`, while `body1` in the Material Design specification was named `bodyText1` in Flutter 1.17, but has also been deprecated in favour of `displayLarge`.

In your usecase with the Google Fonts library, to obtain a `TextStyle` you should use:

```dart
final TextStyle TEXT_STYLE = GoogleFonts.lato(textStyle: Theme.of(context).textTheme.displayLarge),
```

replacing `displayLarge` with your chosen theme size. The full list of sizes can be found within the [documentation](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/TextTheme/headline1.html), but if you have overriden the TextTheme, you may not see the actual font size changes.